# Xcode 11 Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Tags: ios, react-native

I recently upgraded (painfully) from react-native 0.59.10 to 0.61.2 and when I build and run thru Xcode 11 the splash screen loads but then errors show up in the console and the app doesn't load.

I've tried:

cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod cache clean --all && pod install && cd ..

react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios

and done another clean install of react-native but to no avail.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "clean": "react-native-clean-project"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-config": "^0.11.5",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^3.2.4",
    "react-native-nfc-manager": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-pagination": "^1.2.8",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "scheduler": "^0.16.2",
    "urijs": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^3.2.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    }
  }
}
```

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'my_app' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'
  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

  target 'my_appTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end


  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React"
        target.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I expect that my application would load but instead I get the following errors:

```
    2019-10-16 10:25:06.379 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
    2019-10-16 10:25:06.381 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
    2019-10-16 10:25:06.388 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
    2019-10-16 10:25:06.390 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

Comment: Can you share your App.js or wherever you are calling your AppRegistry?

Comment: Thanks for responding @ageoff. I actually just fixed the issue. During the upgrade it unlinked 2 dependencies that didn't get added to the pod file automatically that I had to manually add to the Podfile. For reference it was

    pod 'react-native-nfc-manager', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-nfc-manager/'
    pod 'react-native-geolocation', path: '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue. Was missing dependencies from the upgrade that didn't add to Podfile automatically. For reference, in my case it was:

```
pod 'react-native-nfc-manager', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-nfc-manager/'
pod 'react-native-geolocation', path: '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'
```

Comment: How did you figure out which dependencies were missing?

Comment: @djbuck ^ any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You probably used open and closed tags to introduce a component.

Wrong method:

```
<MyComponent></MyComponent>
```

Correct method:

```
<MyComponent/>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a newer React-Native version(in my case it is 0.62, but I think it will work in 0.61.2 as well) you do not need to put native module pods explicitly in Podfile.

`use_native_modules!` below your other native libraries. With Pod install this will auto-link the Native Modules from node_modules folder.

Previous Answer is right at its place but, just assume if you have lot of node modules, it can be headache to manually link in Podfile. So, your podfile will look like

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'my_app' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'


  ###### This line does the magic here. #######
  use_native_modules!
  ###############################

  target 'my_appTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end


  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React"
        target.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end
end
```